# Per-page count of the Kyocera SNMP printer

Tags: snmp

I am trying to create a project to insert the counts of my printer into the database or into a text file.
To create a .txt file with the general total counts, by color and black, both prints and copies I use the following OIDs with the following command lines in ubuntu:

**Total counter:**

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1 > /var/www/html/wordpress/total.txt`

**Total copies**

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.1.1.1.2 > /var/www/html/wordpress/totalcopias.txt`

**Total impressions**

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.1.1.1.1 > /var/www/html/wordpress/totalimpressões.txt`

**Total de impressão a preto**

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.2.1.1.1 > /var/www/html/wordpress/totalimpressõespreto.txt`

**Total de impressão a cores**

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.2.1.1.1.3 > /var/www/html/wordpress/totalimpressõescores.txt`

**Total de cópias a preto**

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.2.1.1.2.1 > /var/www/html/wordpress/totalcopiaspreto.txt`

**Total de cópias a cores**

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.2.1.1.2.3 > /var/www/html/wordpress/totalcopiascores.txt`

But I created my users in my printer and I control monthly impressions and copies per user.
But so far, first I do not know if it is possible to access this information with OID, but if it is possible I have not yet found the OID to register in a text file as in the examples above.

Comment: Did you look in the MIB for your printer? Which printer is it? Does it have documentation? Have you contacted the vendor?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Is it a kyocera taskalfa 4551ci, will it be possible to do what I want?

Comment: What about the answers to my other questions?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I have not told the supplier yet. I already looked for the MIB but I did not find it. Already searched in the documentation but does not talk about anything MIB

Comment: How are you using it without the MIB as reference?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I am using printer IP on the network

Comment: Yes but how do you know what the OIDs are? How do you know what they mean and how to interpret them?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Because where I found them I had this information and I tested what each one does. But I think I've already found the OIDs I need, [link](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/1347/KMCOMMON.html)

Comment: Okay you really need to contact the vendor for actual documentation rather than guessing :)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, 
with the program MIB WALK I was able to discover the OID that identifies the user, but now I do not know how to insert it into the database table, I will register if it was a copy or print and whether it is color or black. Can you help with this difficulty?

Comment: You should contact the vendor and ask for documentation.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, The problem is that there is an intermediate company, where I already asked for this documentation and the answer was that I did not even know it. My printer is Kyocera Taskalfa 4551

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I have the original printer CD but no OID repositories

Comment: Talk to Kyocera, Bruno. They have the information you need.